# Remove line with specific word from text area using javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am trying to remove line with specific word using javascript from textarea.

Here is example

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxPh1tgiK2g&index=0&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOYPv7CxMVk&index=1&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKC7-ACrs1w&index=2&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE2EuZZCMYE&index=3&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
```

If the user enters the value in input field the line which contains it should be removed. Suppose user enters `CxPh1tgiK2g` or `xOYPv7CxMVk` the line which contains those ids should be removed

Comment: What did you do so far, please post your tries

Comment: @MaximShoustin I am able to find whether the string is there or not using indexOf but how can I replce complete with empty space or else remove it

Comment: So post your code, we will help you.

Comment: You should be able to do it with `String.prototype.replace`. For usage check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$("#remove").click(function() {
  var text = $("#id").val()

  var lines = $('#textarea').val().split('\n');

  lines = lines.filter(function(val) {
    if (val.match(text)) return false
    else return true

  })
  
  $('#textarea').text(lines.join('\n'))

})

$("#replace").click(function() {
  var text = $("#id").val()

  var lines = $('#textarea').val().split('\n');

  var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*lines.length)
  lines[n] = lines[n].replace(/\?v=([A-Za-z0-9]){11}/, "?v="+text)
  
  $('#textarea').text(lines.join('\n'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="id" />
<input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove" />
<input type="button" id="replace" value="Replace" />
<br/>

<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="150">
www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxPh1tgiK2g&index=0&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOYPv7CxMVk&index=1&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKC7-ACrs1w&index=2&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE2EuZZCMYE&index=3&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks I have small doubt how can I replace 11 characters followed by = symbol with particular variable

Comment: @sravyanaidu I assume you need to replace 11 char followed by `?v=`, check above answer. You can change regex to match up with your requirements

Comment: not able to replace properly i need to replece them with one click

Comment: It does, enter something on textbox and click replace. It will replace one `random` line in textarea. You might need to click multiple times as it selects randomly

Answer (score 0):

As solution to remove line with inclusion

```js
var value = test.value.split(/\n/g).filter(function(val)
{
  return val !== "";
});
console.log(value);
setTimeout(function()
{
   var index = value.findIndex(function(val)
   {
     return val.includes('kKC7-ACrs1w');
   });
   if (index !== -1)
   {
     value.splice(index, 1);
     test.value = value.join("\n");
   }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.text {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
Line with <b>kKC7-ACrs1w </b>will be removed in 2 secs
<textarea name="" id="test" class=text >
www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxPh1tgiK2g&index=0&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOYPv7CxMVk&index=1&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKC7-ACrs1w&index=2&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE2EuZZCMYE&index=3&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var ta = document.querySelector("textarea");
var lines = ta.innerHTML.split("\n");
var id = "omg";

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i ++) {
  if (lines[i].indexOf(id) > -1) {
    lines.splice(i, 1);    
  }
}

ta.innerHTML = lines.join("\n");
```

```html
<textarea>
lol
omg
js
</textarea>
```